# Returning data via pointers from C++ to Java using JNI

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, swig

I have a function in C++ which has pointers as function arguments as defined here:

```
get_Message_Tag_Code_(double  * pCurrentTag, int * pCurrentCode, char *receiveBuffer, int sizeOfBuffer)
```

I would like to use this function in Java code using JNI.
SWIG has converted this function in java as below:

```
get_Message_Tag_Code_(SWIGTYPE_p_double pCurrentTag, SWIGTYPE_p_int pCurrentCode, String receiveBuffer, int sizeOfBuffer)
```

How can I get the value of what is pointed with SWIGTYPE_p_double and SWIGTYPE_p_int?

Thanks

Comment: [cpointers.i](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Library.html#Library_nn4) answers your immediate question, but I think the reality is you'd probably prefer to give Java users of your API a nicer interface to work with. Can you say a bit more about the semantics of your function please?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your C++ signature doesn't tell us the semantics of the pointed-to things.  Are they inputs or outputs, or both?

For the general in-out case, put your parameters into a struct, create a wrapper method for that, and SWIG the wrapper (I'm using std::vector mapping , see [swig vector](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Library.html#Library_std_vector)):

```
struct MyArgs {
    double currentTag;
    int currentCode;
    std::vector<char> buffer;
}
get_Message_Tag_Code_wrap(MyArgs* args) {
    get_Message_Tag_Code_(&args->currentTag, &args->currentCode, &buffer.at(0), buffer.size());
}
```

Admittedly I am maybe cheating taking the address of vector::at(), but I've found that it always produces the array address.